# Close app when downloading an enterprise build - iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, enterprise-distribution

We are using the enterprise distribution system internally for our product and everything was working fine on iOS7.

When there is an update to the app, we pop open a UIWebView and show the download link.  The use then clicks the download link and the app minimizes and downloads and then the user can reopen the app.

In iOS8 it seems like the link is being downloaded in the background?  It keeps freezing also.  Is there a way to minimize or notify the user that the app is downloading and then reopen / refresh after the app finishes updating?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using `UIWebView` inside the App, how about opening in external Safari browser? You can even exit the App after popping up Safari by `exit(0)` since your App is an enterprise build.

Comment: Thats what I was going to try if I couldn't get it working in the current state (it's so much nicer inline though).  Can you always exit the app with exit(0)?  Is that a graceful exit or kill statement?  Thanks for the comment - appreciate the help!

Comment: Apple does not allow `exit(0)` in normal circumstances; Apps that intentionally quit via this method will be rejected.

Comment: having the same issue, we can't exit since we open the direct url of plist file with itms-services protocol and we don't know if user proceeded with update or cancelled the OS prompt, and if he didn't proceed, we shouldn't kill the app. I guess one way would be to show a prompt telling user how it all works or redirect to a webpage in safari where download link is provided.